# Call postgres function from ArcPy, returning set of features

Tags: python, postgresql, arcgis, arcpy

I'm trying to execute a postgresql function through ArcPy;

```
cfg = config()
sde_conn = cfg.sdeConnection()
features = sde_conn.execute(cfg.sqlSearchQuery().format(parameters[0]))
```

On the last line, it crashes with:

```
AttributeError: AttributeError(u'ArcSDESQLExecute: SreamBindOutputColumn ArcSDE Error -65 \ud490',)
```

`cfg.sqlSearchQuery().format(parameters[0])` boils down to the simple query:

> SELECT * FROM test_func('some string')

The function returns a subset of rows (features) in a table (feature class)
I have tested the function from pgAdmin query and it works.

Any ideas are appreciated!